# Does MAPIGetDefaultMalloc() require the caller to subsequently release the memory?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, com, mapi

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/opening-a-message), to open an Outlook message using MAPI, you do this:

```
 LPMESSAGE pMessage = NULL;
 LPMALLOC pMalloc = MAPIGetDefaultMalloc();
 hr = OpenIMsgOnIStg (NULL, MAPIAllocateBuffer, MAPIAllocateMore,
                     MAPIFreeBuffer, pMalloc, NULL, pStorage,
                     NULL, 0, 0, &pMessage);
```

I wasn't clear on whether the `pMalloc` pointer would need to be released later on. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/mapigetdefaultmalloc) is the function documentation, and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/managing-memory-in-mapi) is some more info that I do not quite understand.  And more specifically, if you were to use a `CComPtr<IMalloc>`, would you do an assignment or an attachment to the pointer returned by `MAPIGetDefaultMalloc()`?

Comment: @JonathanPotter not true. `MAPIGetDefaultMalloc()` returns an `IMalloc*` interface pointer whose refcount has been incremented, so calling `Release()` on it (such as via `CComPtr<IMalloc>`) is needed

Comment: @RemyLebeau Lol, you're right. I just fixed a 20 year old leak :)

Comment: So then `CComPtr<IMalloc>::Attach` is the way to go?

Comment: @JonathanPotter not think that was real leak in your code. usual `MAPIGetDefaultMalloc( )` simply return result from `CoGetMalloc` and this api return global object, which ignore addref/release calls. and possible any implementation of `IMalloc` pass to `OpenIMsgOnIStg`. possible direct call `CoGetMalloc` instead `MAPIGetDefaultMalloc`. but release formal need on interface

Comment: Does the `CComPtr` constructor have the same effect as `Attach` (in other words, not increasing the refcount)?

Comment: [CComPtr::Attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptrbase-class) takes ownership (but doesn't increment the reference count). The [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptr-class#ccomptr), on the other hand, does take ownership and increments the reference count on the interface pointer (provided that it's non-null). This is not spelled out in the documentation; I had to look at the source code.

Comment: The 'documentation' is certainly confusing. Or rather, devoid of any useful information. If, what Remy states above is accurate, you should `Attach` the return value of `MAPIGetDefaultMalloc` to a `CComPtr`. That'd implement proper resource management (i.e. `Release` the interface, when the smart pointer goes out of scope).